# Android Kotlin: Make view class pass after it's finished to work

Tags: android, kotlin

I'd like to make my app displays texts one by one, with typewriter effect. I made a custom view for the effect. When the first custom view finishes displaying the texts, my app would wait for a click on the screen, or the layout. On the click, the next custom view starts to display texts, and when it finishes it waits for a click, and so on.

This is the custom view I made:

```
class TypeWriterView: AppCompatTextView {
private var mText: CharSequence? = null
private var mIndex = 0
private var mDelay: Long = 150 // in ms

  constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

  private val mHandler: Handler = Handler()
  private val characterAdder: Runnable = object : Runnable {
      override fun run() {
          text = mText!!.subSequence(0, mIndex++)
          if (mIndex <= mText!!.length) {
              mHandler.postDelayed(this, mDelay)
          }
      }
  }

  fun commence(txt: CharSequence?, delay: Long) {
    mText = txt
    mIndex = 0
    text = ""
    mDelay = delay
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder)
    mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay)
  }
}
```

To make it work like I mentioned above, I thought it would need to pass some values to activity(in my case it's actually a fragment) on finish, so I searched some and put some code in run() method.

```
override fun run() {
   val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
       text = mText!!.subSequence(0, mIndex++)
       if (mIndex <= mText!!.length) {
           mHandler.postDelayed(**this**, mDelay)
       }
   }
   runBlocking {
       job.join()
       // pass value after finishing to display texts
   }
}
```

Then "**this**" gets red underline with the error message saying:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Runnable
Found: CoroutineScope
```

So what should I put here instead of "this"? Or are there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Handler` is of no use when you are using coroutines.

The `delay()` should be used to delay the execution, and you don't need to push Runnable to the thread again and again.

```kotlin
class TypeWriterView: AppCompatTextView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    suspend fun commence(txt: CharSequence?, delayMs: Long) {
        if (txt == null) return

        var index = 0
        while (index < txt.length) {
            text = txt.subSequence(0, ++index)
            delay(delayMs)
        }
    }

    // Get [Job] reference after launching in [owner]
    fun commenceOnLifecycle(owner: LifecycleOwner, txt: CharSequence?, delayMs: Long): Job =
            owner.lifecycleScope.launch { commence(txt, delayMs) }
}
```

LifecycleOwner is implemented by Activity, Fragment, etc. whichever has a lifecycle attached (more info: [LifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner)), it dispatches job to Dispatchers.Main by default so UI can be changed.